# Multiple Select drop down menu in android

Tags: javascript

I am developing webpages for iphone and android. I would like to have a drop down menu to be able to select multiple values. But when I use the keyword "multiple" in  it automatically makes it a listBox. I do not want it to be a listBox, I just want a menu to drop down when the user selects it and to be able to select multiple values from the phone without implementing checkboxes next to values or anything of that sort.

```
<select name="planets" style="width:140px" multiple>
<option value="ALL" selected="selected">All planets</option>
<option value="MERCURY">Mercury</option>
<option value="VENUS">Venus </option>
<option value="EARTH">Earth</option>
<option value="MARS">Mars</option>
</select>
```

The above piece of code in a js file creates a listbox due to the keyword "multiple". But in the iphone this piece of code does not create a listbox, it creates a drop down menu without a listbox able to select multiple values, which is exactly what I want. But the same code does not work for an android phone or in safari.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.